How can I load account with balance in benchmark?
Here is my benchmark code:
    #[benchmark]
    fn apply_staking_period() {
        let tipping_name = TippingName::SmallTipper;
        let tipping_value = ProjectTips::<T>::value_of_tipping_name(tipping_name);
        let max_tipping_value = tipping_value.max_tipping_value;
        let sub_value = ProjectTips::<T>::u64_to_balance_saturated(100);
        let funding_needed = max_tipping_value - sub_value;
        let content: Content = Content::IPFS(
            "bafkreiaiq24be2iioasr6ftyaum3icmj7amtjkom2jeokov5k5ojwzhvqy"
                .as_bytes()
                .to_vec(),
        );

        let account1 = account::<T::AccountId>("account1", 1, SEED);
        assert_ok!(ProjectTips::<T>::create_project(
            RawOrigin::Signed(account1.clone()).into(),
            2,
            content,
            tipping_name,
            funding_needed
        ));

        #[extrinsic_call]
        apply_staking_period(RawOrigin::Signed(account1), 1);


It gives error, because account1 has no balance, how can I load the account with balance:
Error: Input("Benchmark pallet_project_tips::apply_staking_period failed: InsufficientBalance") 


Simply deposit creating for that account.
Example: https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot-sdk/blob/b16237ad6f019667a59b0e3e726f6ac20e2d0a1c/substrate/frame/assets/src/benchmarking.rs#L106-L109.
